# Write text into file in C: Ctrl + D doesn't work on Windows

Tags: c, windows

I want to write text into a file using C.

This is the code I tried :

```
int ecrire(){
    char buf[1024];
    int bytesStored;
    int fildes;
    char path[128];
    int i=0;
    int flags = O_WRONLY;
    printf("\n-->Donner l'emplacement du fichier : ");
    scanf("%s", path);
    fildes = ouvrir(path, flags);
    if(fildes == -1){
        return 0;
    }
    printf("\n-->Enter le contenu pour le fichier ");
    printf("(Appuyer CTRl+D a la fin du fichier) : \n");
    fflush(stdin);
    while((buf[i] = getc(stdin)) != EOF) i++;
    buf[i] = '\0';
    bytesStored = strlen(buf);
    if(write(fildes,buf,bytesStored) < 0){
        return 0;
    }
    close(fildes);
    return 1;
}

int ouvrir(char *path, int flags_t)
{
    return open(path, flags_t);
}
```

The user will be able to do carriage returns while he's writing the text, until he press <kbd>CTRL+D</kbd> on keyboard.

In Linux It worked, but in Windows when I press <kbd>CTRL+D</kbd>, nothing happens.

How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl + D</kbd> in Linux generates EOF (End of File). In Windows the key you need is <kbd>Ctrl + Z</kbd>.

Comment: On Windows, you must press Enter/Return after Ctrl-Z.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but there are some mistakes in your code:

First: Your buffer sizes (the most important issue). If you write a line like

```
char buf[1024];
```

this is a promise to your compiler: You will never try to store more than 1024 characters in this array (and if you want `buf` to contain a 0-terminated string, you can store only 1023 characters and a trailing 0-byte at `buf[1023]`)

You renege on your promise here:

```
while((buf[i] = getc(stdin)) != EOF) i++;
buf[i] = '\0';
```

where you don't check `i` to be smaller than (and not equal to) 1023 (you need 1 byte for the terminator), which it eventually will become, if the user enters that many characters.

This may lead to another buffer overflow:

```
char path[128];
scanf("%s", path);
```

where you promise the compiler that the arbitrary-lengthed user input is not longer than 127 characters.
Use either

```
scanf("%127s", path);
```

or (makes error handling easier)

```
fgets(path, sizeof(path), stdin);
```

(to be precise: The `fgets` call is strictly conforming only as long as `sizeof(path)` doesn't evaluate to something larger than `INT_MAX` (since the result of `sizeof` has type `size_t`, not `int`), but if this happens (which is unlikely to happen anyway for reasonable buffer sizes) your compiler should give you a warning).

In the code snippet above with the `while`-statement, there is another common mistake: `EOF` is not representable as a `char` (at least, not necessarily), but the result of the assignment `buf[i]=getc(stdin)` is of type `char`, since `buf[i]` is of that type, so there may be a character in the input interpreted as end-of-file (<del>a `char` which is equal to `(char)EOF`</del>) [It may lead to implementation-defined behavior, or a signal may be raised. It's late, and I'm not sure, what else could happen, but at least, this doesn't work :)].

Finally, the behaviour of using `fflush` on input streams is undefined.

Whatever book or online-tutorial (or whatever) you picked up to learn C: If it contains a call to `gets()` or a call to `scanf()` with the first argument containing the sequence `"%s"` I would advice you to switch to another one.